# How can I conditionally animate a storyboard segue in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

I've added a Quick Action to my iOS app.  When I handle the action, I perform a modal segue I created in the storyboard.  If the app is already launched, it comes to the foreground with the destination view controller already visible.  However, if the app is not already launched, you see the presenting view controller and then the destination view controller animates into view.  I'd like to make it so when you select the Quick Action, you see the destination view controller without it animating into view.

Comment: Try to change rootviewcontroller in your appdelegate file. self.window.rootViewController = destionationViewController

Comment: You got the answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your `ViewController` as your app's `rootViewController` in `App Delegate`. You can do that like this.

```
 let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let rootViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YouControllersStoryBoardIDHere")
 self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
 self.window!.rootViewController = rootViewController
 self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Put this code in your `App Delegat's` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Check your Quick Actions type, corresponding to that call this with appropriate view controller's storyboard id.

Comment: Is it still possible to have view dismiss in a modal fashion when the "Cancel" or "Done" buttons are tapped?